# Quake3 error during installation - cannot stat `Installed/Quake-3/baseq3/pak0.pk3': No such file or directory

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dpkg, games

I am getting the following error during every installation:

```
Setting up quake3-data (1-0ubuntu2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/quake3-data.postinst: 24: [: /host/Games: unexpected operator
/var/lib/dpkg/info/quake3-data.postinst: 32: [: /host/Games: unexpected operator
cp: omitting directory `/host/Games'
cp: cannot stat `Installed/Quake-3/baseq3/pak0.pk3': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing quake3-data (--configure)
```

I just used this command:

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -r ubuntu-docs
```

I can reinstall the fglrx driver again, but to be honest, I don't know how it got removed. I must have done something while playing with compiz.
So I just installed fglrx and hope things work out fine.

Now I want to get rid of that quake3 error.

Answer (score 1):

That's clearly a bug in the quake3-data package, that it doesn't allow a space in the CDROM path.

I suggest purging it (not the entirely unrelated ubuntu-docs).

If it won't let you purge it, edit `/var/lib/dpkg/info/quake3-data.postinst` and put an `exit 0` in the first blank line. It should purge, then.

Please [file a bug](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ReportingBugs), this package is broken.